# Using WITH clause in Jasper report (JRXML file)

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to use the WITH clause in my jasper report query, but it is giving me the error: -
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
and net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No input source supplied to the exporter.

The same query works perfectly fine in the Oracle DB client.

Please let me know if there is a problem in using the WITH clause with Jasper report version 3.7.6.

Comment: Can you post the complete exception stack?

Comment: @SukeshKumar You should post the *queryString*. It should works fine if the query is correct

Comment: Got it fixed. @AlexK you were right. there was a problem in the query

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `WITH` clause in the starting of select query then, you need to change in Jasper report configuration where you need to specify query start with either `SELECT` or `WITH`.

If you are using `WITH` clause in the middle of select query, you might forget to select records from the dataset generated from WITH clause. See below example...

```
select * from (
  WITH temp as (
    select data from any_table
  )
)
```

Instead, use below...

```
select * from (
  WITH temp as (
    select data from any_table
  )
  select * from temp
)
```

OR

```
select * from (
 select * from
 (
  WITH temp as (
    select data from any_table
  )
 )
)
```

Keep Querying!